# Iterating over a vector with std::adjacent_find and custom predicate

Tags: sorting, c++11, stl, stl-algorithm

I am having trouble searching for and printing out pairs of elements in a vector that are separated by 2 from left to right.  I need to collect the pairs

The example data that I am operating on is:

`std::vector<int> myvector = { 1, 3, 3, 5, 7, 9, 13, 10, 12 };`

Given that the std::adjacent_find predicate is:

```
static const auto gAdjacentPred = [](
    const int& lhs, const int& rhs) {
    std::cout 
        << "(" << lhs << ":" << rhs << ")?" 
        << std::string((rhs == lhs+2)? "true" : "false") 
        << std::endl;
    return (rhs == lhs+2);
};
```

I was expecting to get the following result (with multiple calls to the predicate along the way):

```
{1,3}, {3,5}, {5,7}, {7,9} & {10,12}
```

Ideally thought (and I have no idea how to do this) I would like to merge the values that satisfy the predicate in the middle of the input data ... 3, 5, 7, 9 ... as a single result `{3, 9}`.

The problem is that I do not really understand how to properly loop over the collection.  I did see that std::next(iter) is a trick that I can use to peek ahead at the right most value satisfying the lambda, however this can sometimes point to the end of the collection.

I was expecting that the way I was looping over the data would show multiple calls to the predicate as it iterated over the collection - as it turns out it only calls the predicate function one time (when I assign to the `adjIter`.  Also, in the results I see that the pair 13 & 10 seems to satisfy the predicate.  Could someone explain what is going on here as I need to find pairs from left to right that differ by some value - in my case here 2 (with the left side less than the right (I am searching for increasing values from left to right).

```
(1:3)?true
{1,3}
{3,5}
{7,9}
{13,10}
```

The problem is that the last pair is also considered

```
static const auto gAdjacentPred = [](
    const int& lhs, const int& rhs) {
    std::cout 
        << "(" << lhs << ":" << rhs << ")?" 
        << std::string((rhs == lhs+2)? "true" : "false") 
        << std::endl;
    return (rhs == lhs+2);
};

std::vector<int> myvector = { 1, 3, 3, 5, 7, 9, 13, 10, 12 };
auto adjIter = std::adjacent_find (
    myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), 
    gAdjacentPred);
while (adjIter != myvector.cend()) {        
    auto second = std::next(adjIter);
    // print both sides
    if (second != myvector.cend()) {
        std::cout << "{" << *adjIter << "," << *second << "}" << std::endl;
        adjIter +=2;
    } else {
        adjIter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you only call `std::adjacent_find` once. Why would you expect more calls to the predicate after the first pair is found, if you don't call the predicate nor pass it to any function? You are supposed to call `std::adjacent_find` in a loop.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik -  thanks - I just figured that out and I was editing my question (before any answers to really focus on the second part of my original question on how to merge together all the pairs that are side by side so that I could convert the input data ... 3, 5, 7, 9 ... as a single result {3, 9}.  I found how to repeatedly call the iterator here:  https://stdcxx.apache.org/doc/stdlibug/13-3.html.  I was really thinking